# Custom list layouts not working in emulator

Tags: android

New to Android, sorry if there's something I should be including here that I'm not.

Anyway, I'm trying to make a custom layout for a list. Whenever I try to run the app, it closes and sends a "AppName has crashed" error modal. When I use a built-in android layout, this doesn't happen. I'm not sure if the issue is my code or my emulator (Running on a Nexus 5 with 1GB RAM)

Here's `layout/row_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's `layout/activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/theListView"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the `onCreate` method in `MainActivity.java` (I haven't edited anything else)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] favoriteTVShows = {"The Office", "The Wire", "Mr. Robot", "Parks and Rec",
            "Fool Us", "Garbage Time", "Last Week Tonight", "Silicon Valley"};
    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout,
            favoriteTVShows);
    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);
    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                                                   View view, int position,
                                                                   long id) {
                                                String tvShowPicked = "You selected "  +
                                                        String.valueOf(adapterView
                                                                .getItemAtPosition(position));
                                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked,
                                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                           });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the adapter to a view that can contain the text, meaning that instead of using a LinearLayout as a base, use a TextView:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="15dp"/>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there a way I could modify this to get it to use a linear layout?

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html). You just need to choose what you want to populate the ListView: instead of an image and text you could add only a text element.